# Is the given $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=0$ correct while we see the argument of cosine may become close to $\frac{\pi}2$?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, asymptotics

I have this function $f(x)$ for **integer** values of $x>0$.

$$f(x)=\left\lvert\frac{4}{\left(3 x^2\right) \cos \left(\sqrt{10} x\pi\right)}\right\rvert \quad \text{for}\quad  x \in\mathbb N$$

I use Mathematica and it gives $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=0$; with the assumption that $x$ is an integer it gives a warning.

```
Limit[ Abs[ 4/((3 x^2) Cos[x Pi Sqrt[10]])], x -> \[Infinity]] 
(*0*)

Limit[ Abs[ 4/((3 x^2) Cos[x Pi Sqrt[10]])], x -> \[Infinity], 
 Assumptions -> Element[x, Integers] && x > 0]
(*0*)
(*Limit::alimv: Warning: Assumptions that involve the limit variable are ignored.*)
```

**Question.** I am looking for the lower and upper bound of $f(x)$ in the limit $x\to\infty$? Is the $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=0$ correct while as we see the argument of cosine may become close to $\frac{\pi}2$?

Comment: With version 13.3.1 on a Mac, `Limit[Abs[4/((3 x^2) Cos[x Pi Sqrt[10]])], x -> Infinity]` evaluates to `Interval[{0, \[Infinity]}]` and for integer `x`, i.e.,  `DiscreteLimit[Abs[4/((3 x^2) Cos[x Pi Sqrt[10]])], x -> Infinity]` returns unevaluated.

Comment: I use Mathematica 12. Thanks

Comment: "with the assumption that x
 is an integer it gives a warning." You are not allowed to in any way assume the limit variable. That is mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: @BobHanlon It seems that even the website https://www.wolframalpha.com/ is not updated either; it gives the limit 0!

Comment: @math2021 Wolfram Alpha uses older version of Wolfram, 12.0

Answer (score 3):

This is rather math than Mathematica. In 13.3.1 on Windows 10 and Linux
the command

```
Limit[Abs[4/((3 x^2) Cos[x Pi Sqrt[10]])], x -> \[Infinity]]
```

correctly produces `Interval[{0, \[Infinity]}]`. This means that for each real number $a\in[0,\infty)$ there exists a sequence $x_n\to\infty$ s.t. $\left| \frac{4}{\left(3 x_n^2\right) \cos \left(\pi  \sqrt{10} x_n\right)}\right|\to a$ as $n\to\infty$ and there is a sequence $x_n$ s.t. the values along it tend to infinity.

The command

```
DiscreteLimit[Abs[4/((3 x^2) Cos[x Pi Sqrt[10]])], x -> \[Infinity]]
```

returns the input. The possible result is a complex matter related to  [the irrationality measure](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/IrrationalityMeasure.html).

Comment: Thanks. It was a Mathematica question since Mathematica 12 and also the website `Wolframalpha.com' give $0$.